# multi-threading safe usage with SerialPort controller

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, doevents

I have read dozens of articles about threading in c# and Application.DoEvents() ... Still can't use it properly to get my task done:
I have a controller connected to my COM, this controller works on command (i send command, need to wait few ms to get response from it), assume the response is a data that i want to plot every time interval using a loop:

- start my loop.
- send command to controller via serialPort.

  - wait for response (wait let say 20 ms).
  - obtain data.
- repeat this loop every let say 100 ms.

this simply doesn't want to work!!  i tried to communicate with the data controller on other thread but it seems that it can't access the serialPort which belongs to the main thread (roughly speaking).

any help is appreciated

Comment: From my experience, `DoEvents` has never solved any problems. I tend to stay away from it.

Comment: what you use then in such cases when you need it, can you please give me the alternate you prefer ? To gunr2171

Comment: Create the serialPort instance in the secondary thread, use it and manage it there.  Communicate your plot data back with BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.DoEvents is for all it does - nothing more than a nested call to a windows (low level) message loop on the same thread. Which might easily cause recursion if you call it in in an event handler. You might consider creating your serial port object on the worker thread and communicate through threading classes (i.e. the WaitHandles and similar). Or call back to your UI thread using "BeginInvoke" and "EndInvoke" on the UI object.

Comment: Thanks, we overlapped it seems. But as a non-native speaker these answers take a few more seconds to type... at least without too much typos :)

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the SerialPort.DataReceived event and then use wither SerialPort.ReadLine or SerialPort.Read(byte[],int,int) those methods will be executed on a new thread.  I prefer to use a mutex to control access to the buffer of bytes as a shared resource.  Also have you ever communicated with your device successfully?  If not in addition to the port setting check the SerialPort.NewLine property and the SerialPort.Handshake property.  These settings vary depending on the device you are trying to communicate with.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use it to begin with?

Have a look at this pages, it might give you a direction

1. My favorite: [Is DoEvents Evil?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html)
2. From msdn blog [Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx)
3. From msdn forums [Application does not return from call to DoEvents](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9de1d7bd-2e34-449e-bdc3-634c09127541/application-does-not-return-from-call-to-systemwindowsformsapplicationdoevents?forum=vbgeneral)

Without code, it'll be hard to help. Even with code, it might be hard to help :)

I'm agreeing with gunr2171 on this :)

Comment: I would say this is a link-only answer, but one of the links is to Coding Horror, a site that will never die.

Comment: I'd say this question is too broad, and the user didn't even show what he tried ... So ... off to do some reading and show he cares :)